# Find the missing angle of similar triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Find the missing angle $\theta$ in the triangle below given that $R>r$, $l\geq R$, $0< \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$.
[image: Two Similar Triangles]

**Attempted Solution**
I attempted to use similar triangles to find the angle $\theta$ but the resulting expression for $\theta$ is pretty ugly.

$\frac{r}{R\cos\theta+\sqrt{l^2-R^2 \sin^2 \theta}}=\frac{R\sin\theta}{\sqrt{l^2-R^2\sin^2\theta}}$

I would then use some numerical solver to find $\theta$. Any other ways to attack this problem?

[image: attemped solutions]

Comment: Did you mean $0 < \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: yes. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Is the angle at the bottom left a right angle?  It looks so, but is not indicated.

Comment: It is a right angle, which of course enforces the condition posted by @N.F.Taussig.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    S = {S_1} + {S_2} = {1 \over 2}Rr\sin {\theta _1} + {1 \over 2}R{l_2}sin\theta  = {1 \over 2}r{l_2} \\ \\
    {\cos }{\theta _1}  = {{{r^2} + {R^2} - l_1^2} \over {2Rr}} \\ \\
    {\cos}\theta  = {{l_2^2 + {R^2} - {l^2}} \over {2R{l_2}}} \\ \\
    {\cos}{\theta _1} = {\sin}\theta , {\sin}{\theta _1} = {\cos}\theta \\ \\
    {r^2} + l_2^2 = {({l_1} + l)^2}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
We can find $l_1 ~ , l_2$ then we can find $\theta$

$S_1 \to $ The area of the triangle on the left

$S_2 \to $ The area of the triangle on the right

[image]

Comment: I will have to think about this. $l_2$ is a function of $\theta$ so I can not solve for $l_2$ and then solve for $\theta$. They will have to be solved for simultaneously. But you brought up some good points. Especially equating the areas of the triangles

Comment: @John It would be easier if $r,R,l$ are exact figures.